# How would you go about reading a .blend file? I mean all of a .blend file, not just the .obj information

Tags: blend-files, file-format

So, I'm well aware you can export a .blend file to a .obj and read that with pretty standard file i/o in c++.

What I want to know is how to un-obfuscate a .blend file AND

read in the information in the file as text or python code if possible
OR just know how a .blend file is structured or how blender stores data and compiles the .blend, and in what order like the data types and data structures stored

because I want to access the information for the materials used, the animations key frames, the composition of the scene, etc.

EDIT: well so far I've found these useful sources

[Parsing a blend file by Raging Gazebo](http://www.raginggazebo.com/computer-science-topics-blogs/parsing-blender-3d-files-blend-1-of-3)

[The mystery of the blend file by Jeroen Bakker](http://www.atmind.nl/blender/mystery_ot_blend.html)

[plus, his breakdown of the SDNA for v2.56](http://www.atmind.nl/blender/blender-sdna-256.html)

[And this from github for blender file reading linked by user2859](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/tree/1b1a6e0c9298166fee40ebb9b254f973879017bd:/source/blender/blenloader/intern)

haven't found everything i'm looking but this was a lot of help so far.

edit: there may have been important information one [here](http://www.blender.org/development/architecture/), but now it's gone anyone know where the blender team moved it to?

edit: i gave up trying to parse the file just did an exporter in blender's python script, i got it to export the mesh data so far in an obj like format, now working on extracting the animation data. i'm using the api ref in mike's answer.

Comment: This is what I've been able to find [The mystery of the blend](http://www.atmind.nl/blender/mystery_ot_blend.html)

Comment: it's for 2.4 which i know doesn't store its animation the same way as the new versions, anything more updated?

Comment: I'm sorry, no. That's really all I've found. And I googled quite a lot a while ago. But I don't really need it, so I gave it up. I was simply curious.

Comment: thanks anyway at least, hopefully maybe someone else will answer. i expected this to be easy to find, but it's surprisingly difficult.

Comment: If you find it yourself before someone else here does, please post it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: of course, that's common courtesy

Comment: The whole stuff is no mystery. After all it is open [source](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/tree/1b1a6e0c9298166fee40ebb9b254f973879017bd:/source/blender/blenloader/intern). It's also [off topic](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic/6#6) here.

Comment: [link](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/tree/1b1a6e0c9298166fee40ebb9b254f973879017bd:/source/blender/blenloader/intern) thank you for this, this is really helpful and sorry i'm new here. i didn't know it was off-topic, i actually signed up literally just to ask this question.

Comment: The question is not off-topic, it's just too all-encompassing as it is now.  You shouldn't ask questions like "Can you teach me everything about everything?"  Break it down into small manageable pieces that deal with one specific component and you should be fine.

Comment: ah sorry, if i came off in that way, i'm not exactly asking to be taught everything just to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: @user7952: The Document is no longer available, unfortunately.

Comment: @user2859: There is Open Source, and there is Open Source: One is well documented, the other is "we are too lazy to document, find out yourself". Blender, while being great, is a bit of the second category...

Comment: @U.Windl The thing about .blend is, it is more or less a memory dump of blenders internal state and data. Unlike a well defined exchange format it changes with every blender version. So documenting everything is not only pointless but impossible. Pointless, because it is not really intended for exchange or parsing outside of blender. Impossible, because of time constraints and limited team size.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is to use Blender's bpy python module.

```
import bpy
dir(bpy.data)
```

As you will see from the output, you can access everything from object data to materials to screen layout. Here is the [API for BPY](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_release/bpy.data.html).

The bpy module is typically built into Blender, but there are ways to [compile it into a standalone Python module](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule) that you can load from a regular python file.

---

Someone has also taken the effort to write and open source a .blend reader in Java here http://homac.cakelab.org/projects/JavaBlend/index.html.

Comment: thanks, does this basically show me all the data structs in a blend file in order? edit: it's not the full answer i'm looking for but it helps.

Comment: Yes, it shows you all the data structs in a blender file. It's by far the easiest/most supported way of accessing a Blend file.