# Which properties should I read in a Mesh struct inside the .blend file?

Tags: blend-files

I wrote a custom parser for `.blend` files using some of the info found [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23584/how-would-you-go-about-reading-a-blend-file-i-mean-all-of-a-blend-file-not-j). I can read the structs inside the file, one of these is a `Mesh` and I would like to render that mesh in my application. I'm having trouble figuring out what to read from this `Mesh` struct.

I found two properties: `mvert` and `medge`, the first is a list of vertices and the second a list of edges (an edge is a pair of indices to the first list.)

Theoretically this is all I need, but turning a list of edges into triangles for rendering seems non-trivial, the brute force solution is slow and I couldn't find another solution on the internet.

I also found the `mpoly` property, it seems promising since its count is always the number of faces in the mesh, but I can't make sense of the properties (`loopstart` and `totloop` being the ones that seem more relevant.)

So my question is: which properties from the `Mesh` struct should I read and is any of them a closer representation to triangles than just a list of edges?

Comment: Maybe you'll find this page of the Python API manual helpful: 
 https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.types.Mesh.html  .. and the links from it. They describe what a loop is, and how polygons are stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a basic engine you need to extract `mvert` which is an array of the vertices of the model. Within an item of this array the `co` attribute will contain the local vertex coordinate of a vertex. the `no` attribute contains the normal of that vertex.

The `mpoly` contains the face data as edge loops around the face. As a face within Blender can contain a finite amount of vertices you will need to triangulate the faces yourself. At forehand in blender, or later in your own code. An `mpoly` contains a `loopstart` as an index into `mloop` and a `totloop` as number of sequential entries that construct the face.

The `mloop` contains the data for the edge loops. It has a `v` for vertex index and a `e` as edge index.

Comment: To triangulate yourself, you can make a call to bpy.types.Mesh.update (calc_tessface=True), before exporting?